# How do I set a notification folder action on windows?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, notifications

Everytime I or a member of my team performs a task, we move a document that's the result of said task into a specific folder. However, I have to manually check if the folder has new documents or if someone moved something in there and this is not efficient as you can imagine.

**I would like to know if it is possible to setup a windows 7 folder in a way that it notifies me that a new file's been moved in there**. The thing is, I really don't know where to start. *Is it possible to do this writing a batch file*? If there is any other simple way to do it, I would appreciate the suggestion. After I am able to get these status updates, I am looking forward to implementing an email notification system but first I really need someway of knowing when a file's been moved into my folder. ***Please, feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken!***

Comment: There are various ways you can approach this, depending on how the folder is maintained - for example does the folder get emptied manually every day or do the files stay there and accumulate?

Comment: Great question! @foxidrive
The folder is working as a sorts of registry so files should stay there and accumulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple method to show you any new filenames on the console.

What it does is maintain a second copy of all the files in a storage folder in `%temp%` and simply lists to the screen any new filenames that have been added to the folder, as it copies them across.

The first time it runs it will copy all files to the temporary holding folder, and every time after that when it is run it will show you any new filenames that have been placed in the folder.

You can REM the `goto :loop` line and just execute the batch file whenever you need to check it.

Change the location of the data folder in line three.

```
@echo off
:loop
set "datafolder=c:\data"
set "tempdatafolder=%temp%\tempdata"
set switches=/r:0 /w:0 /mir /ns /nc /ndl /np /njh /njs
robocopy %switches% "%datafolder%" "%tempdatafolder%"
pause
goto :loop
```

If files are removed from the main storage folder then they will also be removed from the temporary holding folder when it runs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out! Could you just explain to me or link a website that explains/lists all those `/mir /ns /nc /ndl /np /njh /njs`? @foxidrive

Comment: open a cmd prompt and type `robocopy /?` for the help

Comment: Thanks! That's right what I was looking for @foxidrive